AG Grid : If I use row grouping feature with hidden grouped column then Column aria-colindex are not sequential, how can fix this
For Ag grid table using row grouping feature and setting the hide : true for grouped column then the aria column index is not set sequential for visible column. Even the hidden column index is counted.
This is causing accessibility issue.
columnDefs = [
    {
        headerName: "Qualification",
        field: "Qualification",
        rowGroup: true,
        hide: true,
    },
    {
        headerName: "Name",
        field: "Name",
    },
    {
        headerName: "DOB",
        field: "DateOfBirth",
    },
    {
        headerName: "Location",
        field: "Location",
    },
]

const rowData = [
    {
        "Name": "Akshay Patil",
        "DOB": "13-11-1980",
        "Qualification": "B.Tech",
        "Location": "Noida",
    },
    {
        "Name": "Mahesh Vaidhya",
        "DOB": "13-11-1987",
        "Qualification": "B.Tech",
        "Location": "Mumbai",
    },
    {
        "Name": "Sabitri Pal",
        "DOB": "13-11-1990",
        "Qualification": "BSc",
        "Location": "Mumbai",
    },
    {
        "Name": "Karina Rao",
        "DOB": "13-11-1997",
        "Qualification": "BCom",
        "Location": "Noida",
    },
]

< AgGridReact
    headerHeight = { 47}
    rowHeight = { 56}
    domLayout = "autoHeight"
    defaultColDef = {{
        flex: 1,
    }}
    rowData = { rowData }
    columnDefs = { columnDefs }
    groupDisplayType = "multipleColumns"
/>

Output :
AG Grid Output Column Index
Expected :
AG Grid Expected Column Index
